# Looking for DocuSign iOS URL Protocol for MDM Exception

Tags: docusignapi

I am a member of an enterprise IT team with enforcing an MDM solution.  My users would like to use DocuSign for signage, but are unable to leverage the iOS app.

I need the iOS URL Protocol for DocuSign to allow the app to respond to system broadcasts.  Any insight or where to look would be greatly appreciated.

For example,

Webex = wbx

SFDC = salesforce1

Answer (score 0):

Eric, we don't support MDM at this time.